# how to define hue category number for numerical variable?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'd like to define number of category for hue for numerical variable. For example, I am using columns of depth as hue, the value of depth column ranges from 400-600. in the below code, it only output 4 categories, 400, 450,500,600. I'd like to change number of category from 4 to 8, i.e. with hue of 400,425,450,475,500,525,550,575,600.  How to do it? Thanks

```
sns.scatterplot(x=x,y=y,data=df,hue='depth')
```

Comment: I think you need to use `palette` argument and provide it with either a dict or an instance of maplotlib's `Colormap`.  https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html

Comment: Thanks pavel, I did use palette='coolwarm' like this. I also do like this: viridis = cm.get_cmap('viridis', 12), palette=virdis, and it still not working, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was a little unsure about your question especially the part:

> For example, I am using columns of depth as hue, the value of depth column ranges from 400-600.

Do you mean in a continuous manner? or discrete?
Anyway assuming the range is continuous, we can achieve what you'd like with a binning process.

I start by creating a sample of your data:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from random import randrange

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,50):
    df = df.append({'x': randrange(1,10),
                    'y': randrange(10,21),
                    'depth':randrange(400,601)}, ignore_index=True)
df
```

Then we bin the values in depth according to your specification and use that as a new column for input into hue argument. They don't mention this in the doc but the hue argument for scatter plot requires the same number of rows for all non null rows in the df.

```py
mybins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(400, 425), 
                                       (425, 450), 
                                       (450, 475), 
                                       (475, 500), 
                                       (500, 525), 
                                       (525, 550), 
                                       (550, 575), 
                                       (575, 600)])
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['depth'], bins = mybins)
df['bins'] = df['bins'].apply(lambda x: x.right)
df
```

Now let's look at the results:

##### hue using depth:

[image]

##### hue using bins:

[image]

##### hue using bins but with a gradient hue

```py
sns.scatterplot(x='x',y='y',data=df, hue='bins', palette = "ch:s=.25,rot=-.25")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Geof, it really works. I appreciate your help. That is awesome!